# How to use one footnote for many replicated citation using biblatex?

Tags: biblatex, footnotes

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Repeat the same reference in footnote on different pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71526/repeat-the-same-reference-in-footnote-on-different-pages)

I use biblatex package to render references as footnotes to facilitate accession to them. I noticed that when I'm trying to cite some reference many times in the same page, it places a new footnote for each citation.
I want to place just one full citation footnote for replicated citations, so the output will be:

- One full citation footnote for replicated citations per page.
- A new full citation footnote for a citation (if it was cited for first time in this page) even it was cited in another page. (to clarify citations in printed versions).

Note: I use `\footfullcite{}` to cite references.

Comment: Could you clarify whether @lockstep's solution works for you, or if you want only _one_ footnote for each reference (which implies footnotes numbered consecutively through the whole document).

Comment: @Josheph I edited the question and also replied to the answer below

Answer (score 7):

`\footfullcite` will always give the full citation in a footnote. I suggest that you use the style `verbose-note` and the `\footcite` command (or even better `\autocite`, which is mapped to `\footcite` in `verbose-note`). `verbose-note` will print "a full citation [...] when an entry is cited for the first time", and "a pointer to the footnote with the full citation" afterwards (biblatex manual, p. 63).

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage[style=verbose-note]{biblatex}

\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@misc{A01,
  author = {Author, A.},
  year = {2001},
  title = {Alpha},
}
\end{filecontents}

\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}

Some Text \autocite{A01}.

Some Text \autocite{A01}.

\printbibliography

\end{document}
```

(The filecontents environment is only used to include some external files directly into the example, so that it compiles. It is not necessary for the solution.)

Comment: That still makes one footnote per citation, doesn't it?

Comment: @Joseph: Yes, it does, but it doesn't repeat the whole bibliographic information every time, and I assumed that was the aim of the OP @Deyaa.

Comment: @lockstep: 'I want to place just one footnote for replicated citations ...' to me sounds like a single (numbered) footnote. Now, if I can work out _how_ to do that ...

Comment: @Joseph: Ah ... you mean, some trick with repeated footnote numbers involving `\footnotemark`? In this case, I have now clue right now (plus, such a solution seems potentially confusing to me). Maybe @Deyaa can comment.

Comment: @lockstep: That's how I see it (similar to a numbered bibliography but in footnotes).

Comment: Thanks @lockstep for the great answer :) but I've an issue here, the solution places a pointer to the original citation even the replicated citation is in a different page (this is not suitable for a printed version). Thanks @Joseph for your discussion :)

Comment: @Deyaa: You should edit your original question and describe exactly how follow-up citations a) on the same page as the original citation b) on subsequent pages should look like.

Comment: @lockstep Okay, done.

Comment: @Deyaa: Your request is actually somewhat tricky. I'll try to come up with something, but may fail at it.