# Biblatex. Sorted references in footnote

Tags: biblatex, sorting

I want to do something like [that](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/20787/biblatex-cite-with-footnote-only-once-with-use-of-brackets). I prefer option `sorting=nyt` in `Biblatex`. But with command `\sfcite{}` I don't have sort order like in References.

**Question 1:** Is there a way to sort `\sfcite{}` before they appear in text to made it work like my command?

I made something like that:

```
\DeclareBibliographyCategory{goodB}
\addtocategory{goodB}{ref2,ref1}

\edef\bibrule{\hrule} 
\defbibheading{rule}{\bibrule}

\usepackage[perpage]{manyfoot}

\DeclareNewFootnote{Z}
\renewcommand{\thefootnoteZ}{}

\newcommand{\printbibliographyfoot[1]}{%
   \let\footnoterule\relax%
   \renewcommand{\bibfont}{\normalsize\footnotesize}% 
   \footnoteZ{\vspace{-1\baselineskip}%
   \printbibliography[heading=rule,omitnumbers=true,category=#1]}}      

\newcommand{\printbibliographyFoot[1]}{%
   \renewcommand{\bibfont}{\normalsize\footnotesize}%
   \footnoteZ{\vspace{-1\baselineskip}%
   \printbibliography[heading=rule,omitnumbers=true,category=#1]}}
```

This command `\printbibliographyFoot[CategoryName]` is doing correct sorting but I need to add all references to category manually. It is good at the end of chapter or section.

In **MWE** you can notice the wrong order of references in footnote :

```
\documentclass{book}

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------

\usepackage[colorlinks=true]{hyperref}
\usepackage[backend=bibtex8,bibstyle=numeric,citestyle=numeric-comp,sorting=nyt,defernumbers=true,indexing=bib]{biblatex}   
\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{citetracker=true}
\bibliography{Bibliography} 

\DefineBibliographyStrings{english}{references = {Literatura}}                      
%\defbibheading{bibliography}{}                                                     

\renewcommand{\bibfont}{\small}                                                     

\renewbibmacro{in:}{}                                                               
%\renewbibmacro{in:}{%                                                              
%  \ifentrytype{article}{}{%                                                        
%  \printtext{\bibstring{in}\intitlepunct}}}                                        

\renewcommand*{\finalnamedelim}{,\space}                                            

\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{volume}{Vol. #1,}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{number}{ No. #1,}
\DeclareFieldFormat[article]{year}{#1,}
\DeclareFieldFormat{pages}{pp. #1}


\DeclareBibliographyCategory{goodB}                                             
\addtocategory{goodB}{ref2,ref1}                               

\edef\bibrule{\hrule}                                                               
\defbibheading{rule}{\bibrule}                                                      

\makeatletter\def\blfootnote{\xdef\@thefnmark{}\@footnotetext}\makeatother          


\usepackage[perpage]{manyfoot}                                                     

\DeclareNewFootnote{A}                                                              
\DeclareNewFootnote{B}                                                              
\DeclareNewFootnote{Z}                                                              
\renewcommand{\thefootnoteZ}{}                                                      

\newcommand{\printbibliographyfoot[1]}{%                                            
   \let\footnoterule\relax%                                                         
   \renewcommand{\bibfont}{\normalsize\footnotesize}%                               
   \footnoteZ{\vspace{-1\baselineskip}%
   \printbibliography[heading=rule,omitnumbers=true,category=#1]}}

\newcommand{\printbibliographyFoot[1]}{%                                            
   \renewcommand{\bibfont}{\normalsize\footnotesize}%                               
   \footnoteZ{\vspace{-1\baselineskip}%
   \printbibliography[heading=rule,omitnumbers=true,category=#1]}}       

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------

% Number of each bibliography entry in brackets
\DeclareFieldFormat{labelnumberwidth}{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}

\makeatletter

\newtoggle{cbx@togcite}

% Citation number superscript in brackets
\renewcommand\@makefntext[1]{%
  \iftoggle{cbx@togcite}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont[\@thefnmark]}\enspace #1}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}\enspace #1}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx@togcite}}

% Citation number superscript in brackets (for babel french)
\ifdef{\@makefntextFB}{%
\renewcommand\@makefntextFB[1]{%
  \iftoggle{cbx@togcite}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont[\@thefnmark]}\enspace #1}
    {\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}\enspace #1}%
  \global\togglefalse{cbx@togcite}}}{}

%--------------------------------------------------------------------------
% Mostly verbatim from Joseph Wright
% http://www.texdev.net/2010/03/08/biblatex-numbered-citations-as-footnotes/

\DeclareCiteCommand{\sfcite}[\cbx@superscript]%
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
   \iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{sfcite}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}}

\newbibmacro*{sfcite}{%
  \ifciteseen
  {}
  {\xappto\cbx@citehook{%
   \global\toggletrue{cbx@togcite}%
   \noexpand\footnotetextA[\thefield{labelnumber}]{%
     \fullcite{\thefield{entrykey}}\addperiod}}}}

\newrobustcmd{\cbx@superscript}[1]{%
  \mkbibsuperscript{\mkbibbrackets{#1}}%
  \cbx@citehook%
  \global\let\cbx@citehook=\empty}

\let\cbx@citehook=\empty
%--------------------------------------------------------------------------

\makeatother


\begin{document}

\chapter{Title}
\null\vfill\noindent
Vanilla footnote.\footnoteB{Vanilla footnote text.}
First citation.\sfcite[e.g.][530]{ref1}
First citation.\sfcite[cf.][10--15]{ref2}
Vanilla footnote.\footnoteB{Vanilla footnote text.}
First ``multi'' citation.\sfcite{ref2,ref1}

\printbibliographyfoot[goodB]

\chapter{Title}
\null\vfill\noindent
Second citation.\sfcite{ref1}
Vanilla footnote.\footnoteB{Vanilla footnote text.}
Second citation.\sfcite{ref3}
Second citation.\sfcite{ref2}\footnoteB{Vanilla footnote text.}
First citation.\sfcite{ref3,ref4}

\printbibliographyFoot[goodB]

\nocite{*}
\printbibliography
\end{document}
```

and `*.bib` file:

```
@article{ref1,
    hyphenation = {american},
    title = {Natural Products as Sources of New Drugs over the Last 25 Years},
    author = {Newman, D.J. and Cragg, G.M.},
    journal = {J. of Nat. Prod.},
    volume = {70},
    number = {3},
    pages = {461--477},
    year = {2007}}
@article{ref2,
    hyphenation = {american},
    title = {Natural products as leads to potential drugs: an old process or the new hope for drug discovery?},
    author = {Newman, D.J.},
    journal = {J. of Med. Chem.},
    volume = {51},
    number = {9},
    pages = {2589--2599},
    year = {2008}}
@online{ref3,
    author = {Quintin, C.},
    title = {Les eponges},
    url = {http://christophe.quintin.pagesperso-orange.fr/Liste_Doc.html},
    urldate = {2009-05-03}}
@article{ref4,
    hyphenation = {american},
    title = {Natural products as leads to potential drugs: an old process or the new hope for drug discovery?},
    author = {Anewman, D.J.},
    journal = {J. of Med. Chem.},
    volume = {51},
    number = {9},
    pages = {2589--2599},
    year = {2008}}
```

Final PDF file:
[image: Final PDF]

Comment: I would like to have in footnote an information about cited position only once when it appear in text with labelnumber from main References. But when I have more than one, it appear in footnote in citation order. Everything is ok except sorting. I can do it manually but this is not a desirable solution. Solution presented by `\sfcite{}` is doing everything what I want except sorting.

Comment: In other words ... I don't want to change main sorting in References from `biblatex` package (`sorting=nyt`)  and keep their labelnumber ... I just want to do extra sorting per page when I use command `\sfcite{}` to have [2] before [3] even if [3] appear before [2] in main text on page.

Comment: I think a solution - if there is any - is going to be really complicated. Your citations are essentially created using a modified footnote command and they are created immediately when issuing `\sfcite`. Now in order to be able to sort (order) the references at the bottom, `biblatex` would have to cache the footnotes for one page and then reorder them according to the sorting in the references. Storing the footnotes temporarily (per-page) and reprocessing them afterwards is going to require quite a lot of code-wizardry.

Comment: You probably want something like http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71526/35864

Comment: Thank you for your interest in the topic. But it seems to me that this is not a duplicate topic. 
The main difference is that the `\sfcite{}` command places the items from the References in the order in which the command is used in the text for example [3],[5],[2]. In my topic, I looked for a solution for additional sorting according to the numbering as in References, eg [2], [3], [5] regardless of the order in which the '\sfcite{}' command or similar was used. 
Small References at the bottom of the page with the sorted order as in the main References at the end of the book.

Comment: Mhhh, I'm not quite sure what you mean. If I use `sorting=nyt` with the solution I linked to, I get properly sorted footnotes. If you are still interested in this, please open a new question where you use the new code with `sorting=nyt` and show how it does not work for you.