# Sorted References Appearing on Each Page with BiBLaTeX and Biber

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, biber, sorting

Is there today an easy way to achieve the following with `biblatex` and  `biber` discussed [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71526/repeat-the-same-reference-in-footnote-on-different-pages)?

Unfortunately the code does not work for me as pdflatex produces an error after successfully doing a pdflatex+biber+pdflatex run of the code stated (without showing the footnotes) telling

```
! Undefined control sequence.
<argument> \cbx@sortlist
```

It would be so helpful to have a command like \sfcite showing a sorted list
of cites occuring on one page in the footnote area of that page and a complete reference list at the end of the document...

Answer (score 1):

Sorting has changed a lot since that answer was written. Change the definition of `\cbx@sortlist@init` to

```
\def\cbx@sortlist@init{%
  \global\letcs{\cbx@sortlist}{blx@dlist@entry@\the\c@refsection @\blx@refcontext@context}}
```

This will work for both Biber and the deprecated BibTeX backend.

The original answer in [Repeat the same reference in footnote on different pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71526/35864) has again been updated to reflect the changes, it now works with `biblatex` 3.11/Biber 2.11.

Comment: It might be wise to edit the previous answer, since it is a popular one.

Comment: @PaulStanley I'm not very keen on editing other peoples' answers (especially those where I can't claim to have fully understood everything that is going on), but you might have a point there.

Comment: Generally I agree but if the code is actually **broken** as this is, and you (among I'd guess a tiny number of people) know how to fix it as you do, and the question obviously gets quite a lot of visitors, I think I'd make an exception!

Comment: Unfortunately the code above once again throws the error '! Undefined control sequence. <argument> \cbx@sortlist' as I wanted to reuse the code again. Did again the soring change over the last year? Is there even a built-in solution to biblatex now I am not aware of? Thanks for your help!

Comment: @fermikante Yup, the macro names have changed again. I updated this answer here and also edited the original answer. Incidentally, just the same change was also relevant in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/420394/35864

Comment: It's me again. I am trying now to have two different bibliographies in my document. One bibliography havin prefixlabels, the other one not. I am defining the prefix labels by adding \newrefcontext[labelprefix=P] before the first \printbibliography command, but when using another \printbibliography command having \newrefcontext[labelprefix=] all cite labels refering to entries of the first bibliography turn to 0...

Comment: @fermikante Please ask a new question about that. And please include a full [MWE](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228/35864) that reproduces the problem.