# Repeat the same reference in footnote on different pages - Multiple Bibliographies

Tags: biblatex, biber

I like to use [the code shown here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71526/repeat-the-same-reference-in-footnote-on-different-pages) to show sorted cites as footnotes in each page. The code works fine unless you use two different bibliographies. In the example shown below (same [code as linked above](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71526/repeat-the-same-reference-in-footnote-on-different-pages) + bibliography file + two bibliographies defined), the first reference shows up as P1 in the text as it should, but as 0 in the footnote. Is it possible to fix this? Any help would be very much appreciated...

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[style=numeric-comp,sorting=none,citetracker,pagetracker=page,defernumbers]{biblatex}
\usepackage[colorlinks]{hyperref}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@article{article:1,
author="Autor1",
journaltitle="Journal1",
year="2018",
keywords="own"}

@article{article:2,
author="Autor2",
journaltitle="Journal2",
year="2018"
}
\end{filecontents}


\makeatletter
% user-level citation command
\DeclareCiteCommand{\sfcite}[\cbx@superscript]
{\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
 \let\multicitedelim\supercitedelim
 \iffieldundef{prenote}{}{\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
 \iffieldundef{postnote}{}{\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
{\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
 \usebibmacro{cite:super:foot}%
 \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
{}
{\usebibmacro{cite:dump}}

% save instcount, save key and last inline instcount if seen first on page
\newbibmacro*{cite:super:foot}{%
\xdef\cbx@key{\thefield{entrykey}}%
\ifsamepage{\value{instcount}}{\csuse{cbx@instcount@\cbx@key}}{}{%
  \listxadd{\cbx@savelist}{\cbx@key}%
  \ifnumequal{\value{cbx@tempcntd}}{0}{%
    \defcounter{cbx@tempcntc}{\value{instcount}}%
    \loop\ifnum\value{cbx@tempcntc}>0
      \ifsamepage{\value{instcount}}{\value{cbx@tempcntc}}
        {\ifcsundef{blx@fnpage@\number\numexpr\value{cbx@tempcntc}}
           {\setcounter{cbx@tempcntd}{\value{cbx@tempcntc}}}{}%
         \stepcounter{cbx@tempcntc}}
        {\setcounter{cbx@tempcntc}{0}}%
    \repeat}{}}%
\csnumgdef{cbx@instcount@\cbx@key}{\value{instcount}}}
\let\cbx@savelist\@empty
\newcounter{cbx@tempcntc}
\newcounter{cbx@tempcntd}
\setcounter{cbx@tempcntd}{0}

\newrobustcmd*{\cbx@superscript}[1]{%
\global\toggletrue{cbx@sfcite}
\mkbibsuperscript{#1}%
\cbx@footnote%
\global\togglefalse{cbx@sfcite}}
\newtoggle{cbx@sfcite}

\AtEveryCitekey{%
\ifciteseen{}{\csnumgdef{cbx@instcount@\thefield{entrykey}}{-1}}%
\iftoggle{cbx@sfcite}{}{\cbx@footnote}}
\AtEveryBibitem{\cbx@footnote}
\AtEveryLositem{\cbx@footnote}

% defer citation footnotes to last inline reference instance on page
\newrobustcmd*{\cbx@footnote}{%
\ifboolexpr{ not test {\ifdefempty{\cbx@savelist}}
             and test {\ifnumequal{\value{instcount}}{\value{cbx@tempcntd}}} }
  {\cbx@sortlist@init%
   \let\do\cbx@do
   \dolistloop{\cbx@sortlist}%
   \global\let\cbx@savelist\@empty
   \setcounter{cbx@tempcntd}{0}}{}}

% print footnotes in 'sorting' order
\def\cbx@do#1{%
\ifinlist{#1}{\cbx@savelist}
  {\begingroup
   \blx@resetdata
   \blx@getdata@cite{#1}%
   \blx@setoptions@type\abx@field@entrytype
   \blx@setoptions@entry
   \blx@execute
   \blx@beglang
   \iffieldundef{shorthand}
     {\gdef\@thefnmark{\printfield{labelprefix}\printfield{labelnumber}}}
     {\gdef\@thefnmark{\printfield{shorthand}}}%
   \gappto\@thefnmark{\blx@initunit}%
   \ifhyperref
     {\H@@footnotetext{\blx@driver\abx@field@entrytype}}
     {\@footnotetext{\blx@driver\abx@field@entrytype}}%
   \blx@endlang
   \endgroup}
  {}}

% access internal list of sorted entry keys
\def\cbx@sortlist@init{%
\global\letcs{\cbx@sortlist}
  {blx@dlist@entry@\the\c@refsection @\blx@refcontext@context}}
\let\cbx@sortlist\@empty

\makeatother

\addbibresource{test.bib}
\renewcommand*{\thefootnote}{\fnsymbol{footnote}}
\begin{document}
New citation.\sfcite{article:1}. Another cites\sfcite{article:2}
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=P]
\printbibliography[keyword=own]
\newrefcontext[labelprefix=]
\printbibliography[notkeyword=own]
\end{document}
```

That's the output:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

The code is missing the initialisation of the refcontext with `\blx@getrefcontext{#1}`.

You need to change the definition of `\cbx@do` to

```
\def\cbx@do#1{%
  \ifinlist{#1}{\cbx@savelist}
    {\begingroup
     \blx@resetdata
     \blx@getrefcontext{#1}%
     \blx@getdata@cite{#1}%
     \blx@setoptions@type\abx@field@entrytype
     \blx@setoptions@entry
     \blx@execute
     \blx@beglang
     \iffieldundef{shorthand}
       {\gdef\@thefnmark{\printfield{labelprefix}\printfield{labelnumber}}}
       {\gdef\@thefnmark{\printfield{shorthand}}}%
     \gappto\@thefnmark{\blx@initunit}%
     \ifhyperref
       {\H@@footnotetext{\blx@driver\abx@field@entrytype}}
       {\@footnotetext{\blx@driver\abx@field@entrytype}}%
     \blx@endlang
     \endgroup}
    {}}
```

Comment: The answer in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/71526/35864 is already fixed.