# References and bibliography written as footnotes

Tags: citing, footnotes

I have checked all the previous questions about this subject, but I have not been able to find a simple solution. I want to write the citations as footnotes, with a simple numerical index to indicate the reference. Moreover, if I cite several references in one point, I do not want a single index and in the footnote a list of references. I want a single number for each reference, and if I cite the same reference twice in the text, in two different points, I do not want to print it again in the footnote, with a new number. I don't know if I have explained myself. I want exactly the same result that I obtain with

```
\usepackage[super]{cite}
\begin{document}
...
\bibliographystyle{unsrt}
\bibliography{bibliography.bib}
\end{document}
```

but with the references written as footnotes. As an example

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}


\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
    @book{Foo,
        title={Book title1},
        author={Author1},
        year= {Year1},
    }
@article {Bar,
    author = { Author2 and others},
    journal = {Journal2},
    volume = {2},
    pages = {022},
    year = {2022}
    }
@article {Baz,
    author = { Author3 and others},
    journal = {Journal3},
    volume = {3},
    pages = {033},
    year = {2033}
    }    

\end{filecontents}

\usepackage[style=verbose,autocite=footnote]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{test.bib}

\begin{document}
\null\vfill\noindent% just for the example
Here I want three different citation numbers (i.e. 1-3)\autocite{Foo,Bar,Baz}.\\ 
Recurrent citation, I want just the index already used (i.e. 3), no reference in the footnote\autocite{Baz}.
\end{document}
```

It seems that the answer here

[Repeat the same reference in footnote on different pages](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71526/repeat-the-same-reference-in-footnote-on-different-pages)

should solve the problem, but I am not able to make it work.

Comment: Can you screenshot the output?

Comment: Welcome to TeX SX! The exact syntax is `\addbibresource{bibliography.bib}`. Also, load `biblatex` with option `autocite=footnote` and use the `\autocite(s)` command.

Comment: Thanks Bernard, I have done what you said. I have also edited the question, to be more clear. @hesham, I think now my question is more clear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems I have found a solution here:

https://www.texdev.net/2010/03/08/biblatex-numbered-citations-as-footnotes/

Here it is:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

%
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
    @book{Foo,
        title={Book title1},
        author={Author1},
        year= {Year1},
    }
@article {Bar,
    author = { Author2 and others},
    journal = {Journal2},
    volume = {2},
    pages = {022},
    year = {2022}
    }
@article {Baz,
    author = { Author3 and others},
    journal = {Journal3},
    volume = {3},
    pages = {033},
    year = {2033}
    }    

\end{filecontents}


\usepackage[style=numeric-comp]{biblatex}
\bibliography{test.bib}
\makeatletter

\ExecuteBibliographyOptions{citetracker,sorting=none}

\DeclareCiteCommand{\notefullcite}[\mkbibbrackets]
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \usebibmacro{prenote}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{notefullcite}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}%
   \usebibmacro{postnote}}

\newbibmacro*{notefullcite}{%
  \ifciteseen
    {}
    {\footnotetext[\thefield{labelnumber}]{%
       \usedriver{}{\thefield{entrytype}}.}}}
\DeclareCiteCommand{\superfullcite}[\cbx@superscript]%
  {\usebibmacro{cite:init}%
   \let\multicitedelim=\supercitedelim
   \iffieldundef{prenote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring prenote argument}}%
   \iffieldundef{postnote}
     {}
     {\BibliographyWarning{Ignoring postnote argument}}}
  {\usebibmacro{citeindex}%
   \usebibmacro{superfullcite}%
   \usebibmacro{cite:comp}}
  {}
  {\usebibmacro{cite:dump}}

\newbibmacro*{superfullcite}{%
  \ifciteseen
    {}
    {\xappto\cbx@citehook{%
       \noexpand\footnotetext[\thefield{labelnumber}]{%
         \fullcite{\thefield{entrykey}}.}}}}

\newrobustcmd{\cbx@superscript}[1]{%
  \mkbibsuperscript{#1}%
  \cbx@citehook
  \global\let\cbx@citehook=\empty}
\let\cbx@citehook=\empty

\makeatother

\begin{document}
\null\vfill\noindent% just for the example
Here I want three different citation numbers (i.e. 1-3)\superfullcite{Foo,Bar,Baz}.\\ 
Recurrent citation, I want just the index already used (i.e. 3), no reference in the footnote\superfullcite{Baz}.
\end{document}
```