# \footcitetext is not recognised (doesn't work) in beamer

Tags: beamer, biblatex

I want to put my citation outside the column (because it needs more space). I found, that `\footnotemark` and `\footcitetext` might be the solution but sadly `\footcitetext` doesn't work. It is not recognised (hilighted red in TeXstudio) and doesn't produce the wanted output.

My code:

```
% !TeX spellcheck = en_GB
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Boadilla}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
  \usecolortheme{default} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
  \usefonttheme{default}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber, sorting=none, style=ieee, doi=false, isbn=false, url=false]{biblatex}
\bibliography{mybib}

\title[Beamer]{Beamer}
\author{name}
\date{date}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
    Col1
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
        \begin{figure}[!htbp]
            \centering
            \includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{fig1.png}
            \caption{Case 2.1. \footnotemark}
        \end{figure}
    \end{column}
    \footcitetext{andrada_switched_2003}
\end{columns}

\vskip 1cm

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \printbibliography
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

mybib.bib:

```
    @article{andrada_switched_2003,
    title = {Switched Reluctance Drives for Electric Vehicle Applications},
    volume = {1},
    issn = {2172038X},
    url = {http://www.icrepq.com/pdfs/ANDR.373.pdf},
    doi = {10.24084/repqj01.373},
    abstract = {Electric vehicles are the only alternative for a clean, efficient and environmentally friendly urban transport system. With the increasing interest in electric vehicles, a great effort is required in order to develop electric drives for electric vehicle propulsion. This paper first tries to explain why the switched reluctance drive is a strong candidate for electric vehicle applications. It then gives switched reluctance drive design guidelines for battery or fuel cell operated electric vehicles. Finally, it presents the design and simulation of a switched reluctance motor power train.},
    pages = {311--317},
    number = {1},
    journaltitle = {Renewable Energy and Power Quality Journal},
    shortjournal = {{REPQJ}},
    author = {Andrada, Pere and Blanqué, Baldui and Torret, M. and Perat, J.I.},
    urldate = {2020-03-26},
    date = {2003-04},
    langid = {english},
}
```

What am I doing wrong? The output is shown here: [image]

Comment: What about with `style=verbose`. Is it ok for your needs? It works for me with this style...

Comment: It works for mee too now. But I'd prefer if, instead of the superscripted 1, I get the number like: [1]

Comment: See my answer but check it before accepting... Thanks...

Comment: `\footcite` (and `\footcitetext`) is usually not what people want with a numeric style like `style=ieee,`. `\footcite` literally just puts the citation label in a footnote. With a numeric style the citation label is just a number, so `\footcite` just produces a footnote with a number. **Note that the footnote number and the number in the footnote (the citation label that also appears in the bibliography) need not coincide.** See https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/542301/35864

Comment: @koleygr looks good but I'd also like the [1] be in regular size.

Comment: @moewe thanks for the hint. I see that this is a massive pain. I want the citation on one hand directly on the slide but on the other hand also with a correct number at the end of ghe presentation in a bibliography (like it is usually done in a technical presentation)

Comment: See my edit ...

Comment: Thanks. That was the solution to this. Now it would also be nice, if the `\printbibliography` would use these numbers too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a way:

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{andrada_switched_2003,
    title = {Switched Reluctance Drives for Electric Vehicle Applications},
    volume = {1},
    issn = {2172038X},
    url = {http://www.icrepq.com/pdfs/ANDR.373.pdf},
    doi = {10.24084/repqj01.373},
    abstract = {Electric vehicles are the only alternative for a clean, efficient and environmentally friendly urban transport system. With the increasing interest in electric vehicles, a great effort is required in order to develop electric drives for electric vehicle propulsion. This paper first tries to explain why the switched reluctance drive is a strong candidate for electric vehicle applications. It then gives switched reluctance drive design guidelines for battery or fuel cell operated electric vehicles. Finally, it presents the design and simulation of a switched reluctance motor power train.},
    pages = {311--317},
    number = {1},
    journaltitle = {Renewable Energy and Power Quality Journal},
    shortjournal = {{REPQJ}},
    author = {Andrada, Pere and Blanqué, Baldui and Torret, M. and Perat, J.I.},
    urldate = {2020-03-26},
    date = {2003-04},
    langid = {english},
}
\end{filecontents}


\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Boadilla}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
  \usecolortheme{default} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
  \usefonttheme{default}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber, sorting=none, style=verbose, doi=false, isbn=false, url=false]{biblatex}
\bibliography{mybib}

\title[Beamer]{Beamer}
\author{name}
\date{date}

\renewcommand\thefootnote{[\arabic{footnote}]}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
    Col1
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
        \begin{figure}[!htbp]
            \centering
            %\includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{fig1.png}
            \caption{Case 2.1. \footnotemark}
        \end{figure}
    \end{column}
    \footcitetext{andrada_switched_2003}
\end{columns}

\vskip 1cm

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \printbibliography
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]

**EDIT:**

```
\documentclass[aspectratio=169]{beamer}
\usepackage{filecontents}

\begin{filecontents}{mybib.bib}
@article{andrada_switched_2003,
    title = {Switched Reluctance Drives for Electric Vehicle Applications},
    volume = {1},
    issn = {2172038X},
    url = {http://www.icrepq.com/pdfs/ANDR.373.pdf},
    doi = {10.24084/repqj01.373},
    abstract = {Electric vehicles are the only alternative for a clean, efficient and environmentally friendly urban transport system. With the increasing interest in electric vehicles, a great effort is required in order to develop electric drives for electric vehicle propulsion. This paper first tries to explain why the switched reluctance drive is a strong candidate for electric vehicle applications. It then gives switched reluctance drive design guidelines for battery or fuel cell operated electric vehicles. Finally, it presents the design and simulation of a switched reluctance motor power train.},
    pages = {311--317},
    number = {1},
    journaltitle = {Renewable Energy and Power Quality Journal},
    shortjournal = {{REPQJ}},
    author = {Andrada, Pere and Blanqué, Baldui and Torret, M. and Perat, J.I.},
    urldate = {2020-03-26},
    date = {2003-04},
    langid = {english},
}
\end{filecontents}


\mode<presentation>
{
  \usetheme{Boadilla}      % or try Darmstadt, Madrid, Warsaw, ...
  \usecolortheme{default} % or try albatross, beaver, crane, ...
  \usefonttheme{default}  % or try serif, structurebold, ...
  \setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
  \setbeamertemplate{caption}[numbered]
} 

\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[backend=biber, sorting=none, style=verbose, doi=false, isbn=false, url=false]{biblatex}
\bibliography{mybib}

\title[Beamer]{Beamer}
\author{name}
\date{date}


%From Werner: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/333024/120578
\makeatletter
% Default:
% \def\@makefnmark{\hbox{\@textsuperscript{\normalfont\@thefnmark}}}
\renewcommand{\@makefnmark}{\makebox{\normalfont[\@thefnmark]}}
\makeatother

%\renewcommand\thefootnote{[\arabic{footnote}]}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
  \titlepage
\end{frame}

\section{Introduction}
\begin{frame}{Introduction}
\begin{columns}
    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
    Col1
    \end{column}
    \begin{column}{.5\textwidth}
        \begin{figure}[!htbp]
            \centering
            %\includegraphics[width=0.6\linewidth]{fig1.png}
            \caption{Case 2.1. \footnotemark}
        \end{figure}
    \end{column}
    \footcitetext{andrada_switched_2003}
\end{columns}

\vskip 1cm

\end{frame}

\begin{frame}
    \printbibliography
\end{frame} 

\end{document}
```

[image]