# Multiple footnote citations of reference on same page

Tags: biblatex, footnotes, citing

If I have multiple footnote citations of the same reference on the same page I get multiple footnote entries with exactly the same content.

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test,
    title = {Synthesis of Enantiopure Alcohols},
    volume = {71},
    number = {17},
    journal = {J. Org. Chem.},
    author = {Test T.},
    month = aug,
    year = {2006},
    pages = {6333--6445}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}

First\footfullcite{test}, second\footfullcite{test} and third time.\footfullcite{test}

\end{document}
```

[image: Example footnote]

I find this to look weird and wondered if something like this was possible:

> 1,2,3   Test T. “Synthesis of Enantiopure Alcohols”. In: J. Org. Chem.
>   71.17 (Aug. 2006), pp. 6333–6445.

If the output in my minimal example is completely normal I am happy to leave it that way - I would just like to hear some opinions on this.

**UPDATE:**
I have done some further research on this and I reckoned it would be the simplest if a footnote citation occurred twice on a page it would get the same footnote.

```
First\footfullcite{test}, second\footfullcite{test} and third time.\footfullcite{test}
```

would give

> First [1], second [1] and third.[1]

**Conclusion:**
My first proposal is very hard to achieve and unnecessary complicated. The solution using "ibid" solves this problem in a different but effective way. If one did not want to use "ibid", Audreys [post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/71526/repeat-the-same-reference-in-footnote-on-different-pages/71566#71566) solves the problem very nicely, too.

Comment: i don't use `biblatex`, so can 't comment on that, but the more usual "extra" footnote content would be "*Ibid.*", i believe.

Comment: Alternatively, you could keep referring to the same reference like @lockstep does here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/11523/how-to-use-one-footnote-for-many-replicated-citation-using-biblatex The question this question links to as a duplicate is also useful here.

Comment: Well, by using `\footfullcite` (or even `\fullcite`), you are telling `biblatex` to give the *full* reference regardless of any other considerations.  There are other ways around this, but using `\footfullcite` in each case is making a solution harder, not easier.

Comment: It isn't clear what you're trying to achieve. If you want the full citation footnotes to recur on each new page, then that problem has been [solved already](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/71566/4483).

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Probably using the `authoryear-ibid` style and using first `\footfullcite` and then only `\footcite` is a little better.

Modifying your MWE to:

```
\begin{filecontents*}{\jobname.bib}
@article{test,
    title = {Synthesis of Enantiopure Alcohols},
    volume = {71},
    number = {17},
    journal = {J. Org. Chem.},
    author = {Test T.},
    month = aug,
    year = {2006},
    pages = {6333--6445}
}
\end{filecontents*}

\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[style=authoryear-ibid,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}

First\footfullcite{test}, second\footcite{test} and third time.\footcite{test}

\end{document}
```

you obtain this result:

[image]

The best way, as suggested by Audrey, would be, anyway, to use the `verbose-ibid` style and simply use `\footcite` for all the citations.

```
\documentclass{report}
\usepackage[style=verbose-ibid,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\addbibresource{\jobname.bib}
\begin{document}

First\footcite{test}, second\footcite{test} and third time.\footcite{test}

\end{document}
```

Comment: There is no need to track first citations manually - replace `authoryear-ibid` with, say, `verbose-ibid` and use `\footcite` (or `\autocite`) throughout.

Comment: @Audrey, you're right (as usual). I've added your suggestion to the answer.

Comment: If I needed to use the chem-angew style, this solution would not be an option, right?

Comment: @gncs Try calling biblatex as follows and see if the result is what you need: `\usepackage[citestyle=verbose-ibid,bibstyle=chem-angew,backend=biber]{biblatex}‌​`